# "'Content-Type' is an unexpected token." error when using the Windows Azure PowerShell module

Tags: azure

What ever command I run from the Windows Azure PowerShell module, I get the same error. Example:

```
Get-AzureStorageAccount : 'Content-Type' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 2, position 18.
At line:1 char:24
+ Get-AzureStorageAccount <<<<  -StorageAccountName "bzyeastussys"
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureStorageAccount], XmlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.ServiceManagement.StorageServices.GetAzureStorageAccountCommand
```

I am completely stumped on what the problem is.

I have successfully set my subscription details (I can do a "Get-AzureSubscription") but any command I use that is calling out to the Azure services gives me this error about "Content-Type" being an unexpected token. I am able to use the old "Windows Azure PowerShell Cmdlets" without issue.

Any ideas on what the issue with "Windows Azure PowerShell" might be?

Thanks.

Comment: do you get a valid response if you just do Get-AzureStorageAccount to enumerate all the storage accounts associated with the current subscription?

Comment: I just get the above error, no matter what I do. Either specifying a specific storage account or trying to retrieve the list. It looks like the Windows Azure PowerShell module does not like the response from the server for any request for anything e.g. affinity groups. Unfortunately, I don't see anyway to find out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is down to there being an internet proxy being used. The request is being challenged for authentication, hence the error.